Can't get polars to read hive layout parquet files from S3 404 Not found
I'm struggling to read data from S3 via polars and just keep getting an unhelpful
Client error with status 404 Not Found

The data is layed out in S3 with what I believe to be Hive Partitioning (although this is the first time we've used it so it is possible we missed something).  See Notes at the end.
Credentials are coming from boto3.  I'm certain they are correct in boto3 since I can use boto3 for other actions on this same data:
import boto3.session
import polars

session = boto3.session.Session()
credentials = session.get_credentials().get_frozen_credentials()
storage_options = {
    "aws_access_key_id": credentials.access_key,
    "aws_secret_access_key": credentials.secret_key,
    "region": _session.region_name,
    "session_token": credentials.token,
}

url = "s3://my-example-bucket/staging/extract/contracts/*.parquet"

frame = polars.scan_parquet(url, storage_options=storage_options)

Neither of these work:
result = frame.filter(polars.col("record_date") == date(year=2024, month=1, day=1)).collect()

result = frame.collect()

The error is:
polars.exceptions.ComputeError: 'parquet scan' failed
The reason: Object at location staging/extract/contracts not found: Client error with status 404 Not Found: No Body:

An Example key in the bucket is:
staging/extract/contracts/record_date=2024-01-01/contracts_0_0_2024-02-15T16:21:51.975005+00:00.parquet


Notes:
This is the first time we've worked with Hive partitioning, so can't fully rule out a problem there. As far as we are aware, the only thing required by polars is for the parquet files to exist there.  IE: there are no other meta files present.  Adding additional meta files or changing keys are options if the problem is with how we've laid out the data.

Are you missing a directory in your glob? url = "s3://my-example-bucket/staging/extract/contracts/*/*.parquet"

@jqurious yup apparently that was it.  What I can't figure out is why that could cause AWS to give a 404, since AWS can't process glob patterns.  I wonder if polars is incorrectly using 404 to mean polars didn't find what it was looking for rather than the server explicitly reporting 404.

Yeah, I'm not sure what exactly it's fetching to cause that error. It should ask for the contents of staging/extract/contracts and then expand the glob: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/blob/2970c5706a5bbc39840ca5b0ffc9d4b3aab502cb/crates/polars-lazy/src/scan/file_list_reader.rs#L155-L156 - It could be a "bug", but I don't know enough about S3/cloud stuff to be certain.

@jqurious yeah it ought to be calling ListObjectsV2 but doesn't return 404 unless the bucket doesn't exist.

As pointed out by jqurious, the answer was the glob pattern needs the correct number of stars to match the number of partition divisions (n+1).
So for a single split of partitions (record_date=...) there must be two stars: s3://foo/bar/*/*.parquet not s3://foo/bar/*.parquet
